# Powershell: Import module in script file

Tags: powershell

I have imported a custom powershell module(.pms1 file extension) in a powershell script(.ps1 file extension), but I am getting a `the term is not recognised as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again` error.

What could I be missing?

**SetUpServer.ps1(powershell script):**

```
$CurrentDirectory=Get-Location
Import-Module -Name $CurrentDirectory\RemoveAddAppPool.psm1
RemoveAddAppPool 'AppPoolName'
```

**RemoveAddAppPool.psm1(PowerShell module)**

```
Function RemoveAddAppPool
{
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param
  (
    [String] $AppPoolName
  )
  {
  Import-Module webadministration
  Import-Module ActiveDirectory
  ..................
  }
}
Export-ModuleMember -Function * -Alias * -Variable *
```

**Update 1: Complete error message:**
[image: Complete Error message, showing error on line 110]

**Call to AddUpdateAppPool module(line 110):**

[image]

Comment: As an aside: `Import-Module -Name .\RemoveAddAppPool.psm1` is simpler.

Comment: As an aside: your function name doesn't contain a `-` after the verb part of your function name (e.g. `Remove-*`); however, given that there seems to be _another_ verb - `Add` - in your name, it's not clear what the name should be - or whether your function should be split into two separate functions, one named `Remove-*` and another named `Add-*` - or, with a single function that either adds or replaces, `Set-*`

Comment: Thank you @mklement0 for your comments, wrt to the third comment, I have updated the post description(i.e there was no error in the code), somehow the code is not working. I will split the function into 2 functions like you suggested

Comment: Thanks for updating, but there's still no explanation for your symptom based on the code posted. Are you sure that the error message pertains to function `RemoveAddAppPool`, and not to _a command inside it_?

Comment: Thanks @mklement0, the code in RemoveAddAppPool removes and adds an app pool, I added the exact error as powershell ISE reported. I will check and report tomorrow.

Comment: @mklement0, I have updated the post to include screenshots of the actual error, the line where the error seems to be originating and a couples of modules that I was importing in the custom powershell module.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I just went ahead with creating a powershell script(instead of modularing it) and calling it from the main powershell script.

```
& "$PSScriptRoot\RemoveAppPool.ps1" -AppPoolName 'SomeAppPoolName'
& "$PSScriptRoot\AddAppPool.ps1" -AppPoolName 'SomeAppPoolName'
```

Thank you @mklement0 for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Basically put your file `RemoveAddAppPool.psm1` inside a folder called `RemoveAddAppPool`. Then import just the folder: `Import-Module -Name $CurrentDirectory\RemoveAddAppPool`

You can see an [example in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module?view=powershell-7.2#example-4--import-all-modules-specified-by-a-path)

Alternatively, you can (and I personally) rely on powershell to find my module via `$env:PSModulePath` - to install a module just copy your file into a folder thats included in the `PSModulePath` list.

Below script illustrates the bare minimum you need to do to make a module work in this way. You can adapt this to your needs.

```
#change this:
$ModuleName = 'SomeNewModule';

#grab first folder in module path - usually inside your users home dir
$OutputDir = ($env:PSModulePath).Split(';')[0]
Write-Host "Using $OutputDir";


$ModuleDir = "$($outputDir)\$($ModuleName)"
$ModuleFilename = "$($ModuleDir )\$($ModuleName).psm1"
New-Item -ItemType Directory $ModuleDir

#change this - copy or download your own psm1 file here instead...
Set-Content -Path $ModuleFilename -Value "function New-Something(){Write-Host `"Im a modules function`"}`nExport-ModuleMember -Function New-Something;"
write-Host "Created $ModuleFilename";


# import the module by just name - powershell looks for directory inside each $env:PSModulePath folder
Import-Module SomeNewModule;

#Call your function
New-Something
```

(Delete the folder `SomeNewModule` and its contents inside $OutputDir to "uninstall" the `SomeNewModule` module)

Obviously dont use `Set-Content` - id suggest either Move-Item/Copy-Item if the file is already on the server, or downloading it with `Invoke-WebRequest` if its on a web server etc. e.g.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://example.com/SomeNewModule.psm1.txt -OutFile "$($ModuleDir)\$($ModuleName).psm1" -UseBasicParsing
```